# Close Button not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I have a button "Close" in a page.

On clicking the button, no action is being performed.

OnClick action is given as window.top.close().

```
<input class="CloseButton" type="button" id="CloseButton" value="Close" onclick="window.top.close();">
```

Ideally on clicking the button the window should close or pop out a confirmation box.

I see this issue in `Internet Explorer 11`, `Chrome`, `Mozilla browsers`.

Closing functionality is working fine in `Internet Explorer 10` and other lower versions of IE.

**Adding additional details:** This window is a popup window which is created from a javascript.

Comment: where you have put that close button `'page'` or `'a js popup'`?

Comment: You can only close the `window` if the window is opened by JavaScript..

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing `window.top.close();` with `window.close();`

Answer (score 0):

you can try it

```
<input class="CloseButton" type="button" id="CloseButton" value="Close" onclick="window.close();">
```

Answer (score 0):

It won't work because of security restrictions.

You could try this script:

```
function closeWindow() {
    // normal close for ie <= 9
    self.close();

    // hack for chrome and safari
    window.open('', '_self', '');
    window.close();
}
```

Chrome and newer IE versions allow close only if it has been opened by Javascript. Hence, the above hack opens a dummy window and then tries to close it.

*Note*: The above hack will however not work for Firefox! And is also not future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<button onclick="openWin()">Open "myWindow"</button>
<button onclick="closeWin()">Close "myWindow"</button>

<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin()
{
myWindow = window.open("","myWindow","width=200,height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p>");
}

function closeWin()
{
myWindow.close();
}
</script>
```